# preg_match in loop returning impossible results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm sure I'm missing something. I know just enough to be dangerous.

In my php code I use file_get_contents() to put a file into a variable.

I then loop through an array and use preg_match to search the same variable many times. The file is a tab-delimited txt file. It does fine 800 times but one time randomly in the middle it does something very odd.

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);    
foreach($blahs as $blah){
$image = 'somefile.jpg';
$pattern = '/https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/media(.*)\/' . preg_quote($image) . '/';
preg_match($pattern, $current, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
}
```

For some reason that one time it turns two URL's with a tab between them. When I look at the txt file the image i'm looking for is listed first then followed by the second iamge but echo $matches[0] returns it in reverse order. it does not exist like echo $matches[0] returns it. It would be like if you searched the string 'one two' and $matches returned 'two one'.

Comment: _"I know just enough to be dangerous"_ - made my day

Comment: Please show your input and indicate the line that is causing the issue.

Comment: `$matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern`

Comment: `.` matches all character except newline.  This includes tab.  Could this be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The regex engine is trying to do you a favor and capture the longest match.  The `\t` tab between the two urls is being matched by the `.` (dot / any character).

Demonstration: ([Link](https://3v4l.org/h48KF))

```
$blah='test case: https://www.example.com/media/foo/bar.jpg  https://www.example.com/media/cat/fish.jpg some text';
$image = 'fish.jpg';
$your_pattern = '/https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/media(.*)\/'.preg_quote($image).'/';
echo preg_match($your_pattern,$blah,$matches)?$matches[0]:'fail';

echo "\n----\n";

$my_pattern='~https://www\.example\.com/media(?:[^/\s]*/)+'.preg_quote($image).'~';
echo preg_match($my_pattern,$blah,$out)?$out[0]:'fail';
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/media/foo/bar.jpg  https://www.example.com/media/cat/fish.jpg
----
https://www.example.com/media/cat/fish.jpg
```

To crystallize...

```
test case: https://www.example.com/media/foo/bar.jpg  https://www.example.com/media/cat/fish.jpg some text
// your (.*) is matching ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My suggested pattern (I may be able to refine the pattern if you provide smoe sample strings) uses `(?:[^/\s]*/)+` instead of the `(.*)`.

My non-capturing group breaks down like this:

```
(?:       #start non-capturing group
[^/\s]*   #greedily match zero or more non-slash, non-whitespace characters
/         #match a slash
)         #end non-capturing group
+         #allow the group to repeat one or more times
```

*note1: You can use `\t` where I use `\s` if you want to be more literal, I am using `\s` because a valid url shouldn't contain a space anyhow.  You may make this adjustment in your project without any loss of accuracy.

*note2: Notice that I changed the pattern delimiters to `~` so that `/` doesn't need to be escaped inside the pattern.

Comment: If I get the one line and put just that in the variable or in regex tester it works. It only breaks when I run it several times in a loop on the same variable that has 5 mil chars in it. Each line is id\ttitle\tdesc\tlink\timglink\t2ndimglink... This is a Google product feed.

I don't see why it would catch the \t because it says to find the http part with a wild card and must end with the file name.

Why would it return "2ndimglink\timglink" when it is "imglink\t2ndimglink" in the vairable? How is that even possible?

Comment: Does my "To crystallize" code block not describe the occurrence well enough? ( I hope that doesn't sound condescending -- that's not my tone)

Comment: I'll admit it is really hard for me to decipher your comment because of the formatting.  Are you able to recreate the issue using my provided pattern?  Does my pattern fail as well?

Comment: Found the real problem. My search data was bad. Somehow I had a secondary image instead of the main one for that one. I need to figure that out now. I have wasted so much time on this. I could have just done this manually several times over for the time I put into it.

Comment: @DavidOgletree No way.  You aren't a loser if you are a learner.  As frustrating as it feels now, it sharpens you going forward.  Either way, I hope that you implement my pattern because it will be more efficient than your original one.  *I should also say, that if you provide a few sample rows of input, I may be able to further refine my pattern for you.